# Oracle SQR datediff, rounding off seconds, and type

Tags: oracle, rounding, datediff, sqr

in Oracle SQR (please, I know how already in SQL, I'm asking about SQR syntax), how can I:
 - determine the "type" of a variable?  I can't find any "type" function
 - what is the data type returned by datediff()?
 - and finally, how do I round off to whole seconds the amount returned by 
 `datediff($date1, $date2,'MINUTE')`?

Thanks in advance.  Searching for this has been a problem because I get back tons of SQL statements and results with square root functions.

Answer (score 1):

datediff returns a number. Numbers are are signified by the '#' prefix (dates and strings have the '$' prefix).

SQR has a round function which takes  (x, y)  as parameters and returns x rounded to y decimal places.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still digging around for a "type" function and have not uncovered one.